# I am trying to add a class to accordion using jQuery option, but it does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to accordion using jQuery option, but it does not work..

```
$( "#AuditLogsList" ).accordion({
          collapsible: true,
          classes: {
              "ui-accordion": "highlight"
            }
    });
```

I also tried this:

```
$( "#AuditLogsList" ).accordion( "option", "classes.ui-accordion", "highlight" );
```

but didn't work.
please help me out.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - also provide a link to the actual accordion you use. There are hundreds

Answer (score 0):

This does work, as can be seen in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JoelAndHowe/p84houry/).
Also on it's own, as can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/JoelAndHowe/p84houry/1/).

Have you included the jquery UI file in your project? Also, are there any errors. I used the code as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="AuditLogsList">

</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
$( "#AuditLogsList" ).accordion({
          collapsible: true,
          classes: {
              "ui-accordion": "highlight"
            }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what event you're trying to bind the addition of the class on but you could try the following:

`$( "#AuditLogsList" ).addClass("highlight");`

The above wrapped in an onClick event would give #AuditLogsList the class "highlight". Also might be useful to check out Jquery RemoveClass and ToggleClass.